# Irreducibility of Cyclotomic Polynomial over a Cyclotomic Extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, cyclotomic-polynomials

I am trying to prove that $\Phi_m(x)$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q(\zeta_n)$ if and only if $(m,n)\leq2$.

The left implication turns out to be somewhat easy since without loss of generality, $2\mid m$ and no higher power of $2$ divides $m$ and using the fact that $\Bbb Q(\zeta_{m/2})=\Bbb Q(\zeta_m)$ (this assumes the degrees aren't relatively prime to begin with, which I think is even easier).

My problem comes in doing the forward implication. I tried and tried without success, so I started trying to use the contrapositive, that is, if $(m,n)\geq3$, then $\Phi_m(x)$ is reducible over $\Bbb Q(\zeta_n)$. This hasn't proven fruitful yet, so if possible, will someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Are you wedded to this formulation? I’d rather have said that for odd $m$ and $n$, $\mathbb Q(\zeta_m)\cap\mathbb Q(\zeta_n)=\mathbb Q(\zeta_g)$ with $g=\gcd(m,n)$. And go from there to the case of even indices. But maybe how to do that is exactly the heart of your question?

Answer (score 2):

First show that $\Phi_m(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ if and only if $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m,\zeta_n):\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)]=\varphi(m)$.  Then compute
$[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m,\zeta_n):\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)]$ and the result will fall out.

Comment: Exactly what I had in mind, using the fact that the big field here is the compositum of the two smaller cyclotomic fields, and indeed equal to $\mathbb Q(\zeta_\ell)$, where $\ell$ is the lcm of $m$ and $n$. The only question is how to get a nice description involving the gcd of the indices, in light of the annoying fact that $\mathbb Q(\zeta_n)=\mathbb Q(\zeta_{2n})$ if $n$ is odd.

Comment: @Lubin, why does that "annoying fact" matter?  Irreducibility is equivalent to $\varphi(\ell)/\varphi(n)=\varphi(m)$, then use that $\varphi(k)=k\prod_{p\mid k}(1-1/p)$ to turn this into $1=g\prod_{p\mid g}(1-1/p)$ where $g=\text{gcd}(m,n)$.  Then observe that this holds just when $g\le 2$.

Comment: Alternately you could use the fact that $\varphi(\ell)/\varphi(n)=\varphi(m)/\varphi(g)$ to show that irreducibility is equivalent to $\varphi(g)=1$, and thus to $g\le 2$.

Comment: Well, @Zieve, I just didn’t give it the requisite amount of thought.

Comment: I'm not sure, but doesn't this primarily focus on the part I already know? At any rate, this part is obvious. If $\Phi_m(x)$ is irreducible, we get an extension of degree $\varphi(m)$, and conversely we already know $\Phi_m(x)$ has degree $\varphi(m)$, so if we know the degree of the extension, it must be irreducible. (Sorry, I've been gone a while and just got on to check).

Comment: No, this doesn't focus on the part you already know.  I proved both the "if" and the "only if" directions via the same argument.  Think about it more, and you'll see that.

Comment: Also, I would suggest being cautious about calling things "obvious".

Comment: I still don't follow, unfortunately. We certainly know $[\Bbb Q(\zeta_m,\zeta_n):\Bbb Q(\zeta_n)]\leq\varphi(m)$ since that is the degree over $\Bbb Q$, so I'm not sure I understand what you mean when you say to compute the degree. If $\Phi_m(x)$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q(\zeta_n)$, then extension to $\Bbb Q(\zeta_n,\zeta_m)$ has degree $\varphi(m)\varphi(n)$ over $\Bbb Q$. Now I'm at a loss, I am still not connecting the dots as to why this implies the degrees are relatively prime or share a factor of at most $2$...

Comment: First show that $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m,\zeta_n)=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_\ell)$ where $\ell=\text{lcm}(m,n)$.  Then you need to compute $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_\ell):\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)]$.  Is there any field extension involving $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ whose degree you know?

Comment: Looks like we’re talking past each other. I think @Clayton must be missing a basic fact that the old guys are taking for granite. You know that $\Phi_N$ is irreducible no matter what the $N$, right? And you know that $\gcd(m,n)=1$ implies $\varphi(mn)=\varphi(m)\varphi(n)$, right? And that $\mathbb Q(\zeta_m,\zeta_n)=\mathbb Q(\zeta_\ell)$, right? Offhand, I can’t think of any other ingredients to the story. The deep fact is that $\Phi_N$ is irreducible when $N$ is divisible by more than one prime. All else is commentary.

Comment: Jonathan, I see two things @Clayton might be missing: how to prove that $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m,\zeta_n)=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_\ell)$, and how to describe $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_\ell):\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)]$ as a ratio of the degrees of two other field extensions.  I'm hoping he'll attempt to do these without someone telling him all the details.

Comment: Well, I’m always open to direct e-mail communications, being retired.